# Many syntax errors in coffee-rails; did I forget to install something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, syntax, installation

Until now, I've done all my development on a computer running Windows. I just bought a Mac, installed Ruby on Rails, and imported my project from github. There are errors everywhere! They all seem to be in the coffee-rails folder, and look like

```
 test "should show post" do
    get :show, id: @post.to_param 
    assert_response :success
  end
```

(error because id: should be id => I guess)

and

This specification aims to formalize the Rack protocol.  You
can (and should) use Rack::Lint to enforce it.

```
Error: unexpected kAND
```

Did I install the wrong version of something, or forget to install something else? Perhaps I'm using the wrong version of rails?

Thanks for any guidance in the matter!

Answer (score 1):

Check your file format, make sure it's UTF8 and you're using the right line endings. Also make sure your indentations are consistent and always either spaces or tabs (not a mix). Sometimes when you develop files on Windows and then run them on Mac the encoding and line endings can create issues. CoffeeScript is whitespace sensitive so you're more likely to encounter this kind of issue in CoffeeScript than in Ruby code.

Comment: I have
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
in my application.rb file. Is that all I need?

Perhaps I just need to fix the 40+ errors one by one... Some of them leave me clueless though, such as the second one above, and 

class <%= camelized %>Test < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "truth" do
    assert_kind_of Module, <%= camelized %>
  end
end

says "unexpected tLT"

Comment: In your text editor you need to convert to UTF-8 and I would recommend using Unix line endings (LF). This is a characteristic of the .rb or whatever other code files themselves, not an application configuration setting. THe errors you're showing sound to me like the parser is encountering characters it doesn't know what to do with, those are most likely hidden characters from windows encoding.